# Low level atom TypeError: new_request() takes 1 argument when calling gdata's SpreadsheetsService.GetSpreadsheetsFeed()

Tags: python, google-sheets, typeerror, gdata

I've been chasing through the maze of twisty passages that is the google apps API documentation. I'm trying to figure out how to use python APIs to update a Google Sheets document.

I'm able to run an OAuth2 flow successfully, and if I'm following things correctly I've generated a valid OAuth2 token and authorized a `SpreadsheetsService` client.

Here's the block of code I'm executing.

```
storage = Storage(CREDENTIALS_PATH)

flow = flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRETS_PATH, scope=SCOPE)
credentials = oauth2client.tools.run_flow(flow, storage, args)

print credentials.token_expiry
print credentials.scopes

gdss_client = gdata.spreadsheet.service.SpreadsheetsService()
oauth2_token = gdata.gauth.OAuth2TokenFromCredentials(credentials)

gdss_client = oauth2_token.authorize(gdss_client)
gdss_client.GetSpreadsheetsFeed()
```

Here's the result:

```
2016-04-22 18:58:56
set([u'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds'])

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./sheets.py", line 159, in <module>
    main()
  File "./sheets.py", line 154, in main
    gdss_client.GetSpreadsheetsFeed()
  File "/Users/browsc3/.virtualenvs/boogio/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gdata/spreadsheet/service.py", line 98, in GetSpreadsheetsFeed
    converter=gdata.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetsSpreadsheetsFeedFromString)
  File "/Users/browsc3/.virtualenvs/boogio/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gdata/service.py", line 1068, in Get
    headers=extra_headers)
  File "/Users/browsc3/.virtualenvs/boogio/lib/python2.7/site-packages/atom/__init__.py", line 92, in optional_warn_function
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/browsc3/.virtualenvs/boogio/lib/python2.7/site-packages/atom/service.py", line 185, in request
    data=data, headers=all_headers)
  File "/Users/browsc3/.virtualenvs/boogio/lib/python2.7/site-packages/atom/http_interface.py", line 148, in perform_request
    return http_client.request(operation, url, data=data, headers=headers)
TypeError: new_request() takes exactly 1 argument (4 given)
```

As the documentation for all this seems to consist of sporadic disconnected descriptions of individual classes as they existed at some point in time, with loose references to external classes that may or may not have specific relevant documentation, I could be doing this completely wrong. I'd be most grateful if anyone can shed some light on my approach.

Answer (score 0):

This link provided the answer:

https://github.com/google/gdata-python-client/issues/25

Replace

```
gdss_client = gdata.spreadsheet.service.SpreadsheetsService()
oauth2_token = gdata.gauth.OAuth2TokenFromCredentials(credentials)

gdss_client = oauth2_token.authorize(gdss_client)
gdss_client.GetSpreadsheetsFeed()
```

with

```
gdss_client = gdata.spreadsheets.client.SpreadsheetsClient()
oauth2_token = gdata.gauth.OAuth2TokenFromCredentials(credentials)

gdss_client = oauth2_token.authorize(gdss_client)
gdss_client.gdss_client.get_spreadsheets()
```

Answer (score 0):

The Oauth and GData APIs are out of sync.

Instead of creating the oauth2token object, just do:

```
gd_client = gdata.photos.service.PhotosService(
  additional_headers={'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + credentials.access_token})
```

That appears to do the trick for me.